# I want to manipulate an iframe's content from the same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe

There is two website loc.something.com and www.something.com. loc.something.com is from a different server than www.something.com. I wonder if I can remove some elements in www.something.com if is iframed in loc.something.com?

I tried it locally it didn't worked? Shouldn't it go. It is the same domain something.com?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this unless the origin URL is the within the hosting URL. An iFrame only displays the contents of the URL specified. You have no control over these contents.

E.g. if the iFrame, and the site it was being hosted on both had TLDs of www.something.com that would be fine.

Comment: He stated that it was from a different origin